# Swift if statement multiple objects, same condition

Tags: swift

I have something like the following block. All vars need to fit the same condition, is there a way to shorten this?

```
@State var var1 = 10
@State var var2 = 10
@State var var3 = 10

if var1 < 15 && var2 < 15 && var3 < 15 {

}
```

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 3):

If the condition is exactly the one you show in your example, it can be shortened as follows:

```
if max(var1, var2, var3) < 15 {
}
```

Comment: Right. So I could read this as "if the highest value of any of these values is less than the comparison, return true"? That makes sense! Thanks a lot.